# SceneKit PBR rendering- displacement map going crazy

Tags: xcode, 3d, scenekit, texture-mapping, scnmaterial

I am using a displacement maps for subtle fabric wrinkles. It should give smooth results, but instead it’s going crazy.

Bellow is a perfect sphere, totally messed by the displacement.

[image]

Is should be like the image bellow, giving subtle wrinkles

[image]

This is my setup:

[image]

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The intensity of your displacement material is set to 1. Try setting this to 0.05 or 0.1

Also, try setting the scale of it (currently 1, 1) to something like 3, 3.

These two:

[image]

Comment: In code: `material.displacement.intensity = 0.05`